# concatenate elements of list with PIPE Delimiter

Tags: python, list, tuples

I require help on the below code.
The code does the following.

Execute the sql query , the output of the sql query is mix of strings,int and date. 
ie

```
10001,New York,Corp,1,20151001
10002,New York,Corp,1,20151001
```

etc.

The expectation is that want to concatenate each record of the sql output and write to a file.

```
10001|New York|Corp|1|20151001\n
10002|New York|Corp|1|20151001\n
```

Below is the code.

```
import cx_Oracle
import os

result = cur.execute(qry)  # -> Execute the sql query.
le.extend(result)

# The output of le is like this , le -> type list

le = [(10001,u'New York','Corp',1,20151001),(10002,u'New York','Corp',1,20151001)]

final_data = []
final_data.extend('|'.join(w) for w in le)
```

Getting error from the above statement.

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

I tried this

```
final_data.extend('|'.join(str(w)) for w in le)
```

but not getting the desired output, `10001|New York|Corp|1|20151001\n`

Highly appreciate if any help on this.

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1):

```
final_data = ["|".join(map(unicode, w)) + "\n" for w in le]
```

Then you can either use `"".join(final_data)` to create a single string which is to be written to a file, or write each element in `final_data` to the file sequentially, depending on your need.

Comment: Hi,Looks great . Is is possible to convert some element as Unicode and rest as string (str())?

Comment: The requirement is to execute the sql query, for each record of the sql output, concatenate the columns with PIPE Delimiter and pass the chunk of data to the stored procedure which will write to the external table. We don't want to call the stored procedure for each record, we would like to call the stored procedure once we pulled 30000K records.

Comment: And this "stored procedure" expects `unicode` or `str` objects? (assuming Python 2.x).  If it want `unicode`, just use Python's `unicode` instance constructor in the code, like it is now.  If it expects `str`, use `str` in place of `unicode`.  Still confused about "some elements as unicode and rest as string" -- "some element" of what?

Comment: regarding the query, "Some elements"    .. Some of the columns of the sql output contain Special characters, applying str() will convert them to string.  We want to convert those columns to Unicode and remaining columns as str() ,something like this unicode(i) if isinstance(i,unicode) else str(i)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for post additional query. The code final_data = ["|".join(map(unicode, w)) + "\n" for w in le] works great. But it add "None" if no output from the 10001|New York|Corp|1|20151001|None\n .... I was trying this lst = [None,'nan']    final_data = ["|".join(map(unicode, '' if w in lst else w)) + "\n" for w in le] . But Still None show up in the list. I would like to get rid of None. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

results = cur.execute(qry)

with open('results.csv', 'w') as rs:
    writer = csv.writer(rs, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work -

```
le = [(10001,u'New York','Corp',1,20151001),(10002,u'New York','Corp',1,20151001)]

final_data = ''
for item in le:
    final_data += '|'.join(str(w) for w in item) + '\n'
```